# Given a number n find the prime number closest to it with maximum even digits

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a challenge to find the prime number closest to any given integer n that has the maximum number of even digits. The code below works and passes all the sample tests. But it times out when the numbers grow too large. Can anyone suggest how I may optimize it?

```
from collections import defaultdict


def is_prime(n):
    first, i = 1, 2
        if n <= first:
            return False
    while i <= (n**0.5):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i += first
    return True


def highest_prime(n):
    dd = defaultdict(int)
    nums = [str(x) for x in reversed(range(n)) if is_prime(x)]
    is_even = (lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
    for outer in nums:
        for inner in outer:
            if is_even(int(inner)):
                dd[outer] += 1
    return max(dd, key=lambda x: dd[x])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(highest_prime(1000))
    print(highest_prime(1210))
    print(highest_prime(10000))
```

test 1 expected value is 887
test 2 expected value is 1201
test 3 expected value is 8887

Edit:
Per the suggestions, since the maximum count of prime digits in a number will always be one less than the total number of digits, I have kept only those numbers whose length is the same as the given integer N. But it still isn't fast enough. For the primality check I used the selected answer at [isPrime Function for Python Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language)

```
def highest_prime(n):
    nums = list(range(n))
    temp = []
    for x in range(len(nums)):
        if len(str(nums[x])) == len(str(nums[-1])):
            if is_prime(nums[x]):
                temp.append(str(nums[x]))
    is_even = (lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
    dd = defaultdict(int)
    for outer in temp[::-1]:
        for inner in outer:
            if is_even(int(inner)):
                dd[outer] += 1
    return max(dd, key=lambda x: dd[x])
```

Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for just a hint in the right direction or a solution?

Comment: What you want is an efficient [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613304/rabin-miller-strong-pseudoprime-test-implementation-wont-work) answer has a Python implementation of Rabin-Miller's algorithm, which should give you a bit of a performance boost. You may also want to take a closer look at your use of `range`.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh a hint in the right direction would be fine

Comment: @AndrewF would I get a significant boost if I didnt reverse range? In that case I'd also need to change the data type to ordered dict. Why is the primality test not efficient, I'm only checking factors until the square root.

Comment: Try the the Sieve of Eratosthenes if you want to find all primes up to a given number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes. A very primitive test takes 3 seconds on my machine to get all primes up to 10,000,000.

Comment: @KabirGandhiok i can think of a way to cut off how many of those prime numbers you need to check for even digits. Put this way... how many digits can be even in a 2 digit prime number at most? What about 3? and so on. (PS. 1209 is divisible by 3, in your example. Its wrong im guessing)

Comment: @ParitoshSingh hmm.. thanks for the clue. Will work on it. Btw 1209 was a typo. The expected result is 1201

Comment: @ParitoshSingh could you please review the edited function, it still isn't fast enough to clear the challenge.

Comment: Ah. it doesn't quite use the hint adequately. Put it this way, why should you have to still collect or check prime numbers if you already find the maximum possible even digits in a number? Do you have the input number for which this fails? I can write something up.

Comment: Because the final result has got to be a prime number with maximum possible even digits. So lets say N = 5000000, the expected result is 4888889 which is what I get but it takes too much time, and so it fails. Another option I tried is by using the code submitted by @AntiMatterDynamite to generate a list of primes and then remove those numbers with not enough even digits. So instead of nums = list(range(n)) I now have nums = get_primes_list(n), rest of the function remains same without any further prime checks, but still not fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major areas of optimization, that you should consider.

The first is ensuring that our prime number checking is decent. Taking a smart bruteforce approach from [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language), You essentially only need to check `6n - 1` and `6n + 1` for all n starting from 1 upto the square root of a number to figure out if it is prime or not. (Because `6n + 2`, `6n + 4` are even, and `6n + 3` is divisible by 3). I have added explanations in the `is_prime(n)` function below.

The second that really makes a difference, is ensuring that you always keep track of "the best possible outcome for even digits". The idea is simple: A prime number of `n` digits can at-most have `n-1` even digits, with the exception of the prime number 2. With that in mind, we only really need to ensure we find the "best case" possible, and instead of accumulating all prime numbers upto a given number `n`, we just find the highest prime number that fits our best case, going from big to small. So, I have `highest_prime_optimized(n)` with comments. I initially planned to compare the times of this with the original function, but once the original function ran over a minute i decided to kill it. This one should beat the tests.

```
import time

def is_prime(n):
    #base cases handling
    if n == 2 or n == 3: return True #handles 2, 3
    if n < 2 or n%2 == 0: return False #handles 1 and even numbers
    if n < 9: return True #since 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 and 8 are handled, this leaves 5 and 7.
    if n%3 == 0: return False #handles multiples of 3
    r = int(n**0.5) #only check upto square root
    f = 5 #start from 5
    while f <= r:
        #print ('\t', f)
        if n%f == 0: return False #essentially checks 6n - 1 for all n.
        if n%(f+2) == 0: return False #essentially checks 6n + 1 for all n.
        f +=6 #incrementing by 6.
    return True

def max_even_digits_in_prime(n):
    return (len(str(n)) - 1) or 1 

def count_of_even_digits(n):
    count = 0
    for i in str(n):
        count+= (int(i) % 2 == 0)
    return count

def highest_prime_optimized(n):
    best_case = (0, 0) #keeps track of highest best case number seen[1], and its count of even digits[0]
    for x in range(n, 1, -1): #iterate in the reverse direction
        #print(x)
        if is_prime(x): #proceed for prime numbers
            even_digits = count_of_even_digits(x)
            max_even_digits = max_even_digits_in_prime(x)
            if best_case[0] < even_digits: #update best number seen so far
                best_case = (even_digits, x)
            if max_even_digits == best_case[0]: #best case answer, your work is done. No need to look for more numbers.
                print(best_case)
                return (best_case[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(highest_prime_optimized(1000))
    print(highest_prime_optimized(1210))
    print(highest_prime_optimized(10000))
    start = time.time() 
    result = highest_prime_optimized(5000000)
    print(result, time.time() - start)
    #Output: 4888889 0.5920031070709229
```

Comment: Wow! That was blazing fast!! And thanks so much for explaining it so well!

Answer (score 3):

there are very clever ways for testing if a number is prime (or at least clever ways that are correct up to a very large N) but in this case when you compute all the prime numbers up to a certain number you can use the previous prime numbers and only check for them as factors:

```
def get_primes_list(n):
    if n < 2:
        return []
    primes = [2]
    for i in range(3,n+1):
        sqroot = i**0.5
        for p in primes:
            if i%p == 0:
                break
            if p > sqroot:
                primes.append(i)
                break
    return primes
```

if you're looking for anything more efficient than this (since this method is still resource consuming and will still take a long time when you get to the tens of millions) your best bet is to find an existing implementation of an efficient primality test like the Rabin-Miller primality test that was mentioned

Comment: That's an interesting take on primality checking though it still times out. I need to get it under 12000 ms for very large numbers. I tried the selected answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285534/isprime-function-for-python-language but it times out as well.

Comment: @KabirGandhiok it's not meant to be the fastest , just improves upon the basic brute force algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Use "Sieve of Eratosthenes" algorithm, which generates the prime numbers less than N.

Hope this might resolve your issue.

**It's Time complexity : O(n*log(log(n)))**

***Reference:***
    https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/